# DoctrineODM - QueryBuilder: filter on Document Reference field

Tags: query-builder, doctrine-odm

I have 2 Documents that references each others (Series and Chapter).
On the Chapter Document, there is a "visible" property that make the chapter publicly visible.
What I search to do is, having a Query to search for Series that have at least one Chapter visible.

In Series

```
/**
     * @var Collection
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
     *     targetDocument="App\Model\Document\Chapter",
     *     mappedBy="series",
     *     strategy="addToSet"
     * )
     */
    protected $chapters;
```

In Chapter

```
/**
     * @var Series|null
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(
     *      targetDocument="App\Model\Document\Series",
     *      inversedBy="chapters",
     * )
     */
    protected $series;
```

I took a look at the complex references pages on DoctrineODM page but I don't think it could help me in my case, as I have to query another Document (Chapter) to see if there are at least one visible.

Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish can't be done with normal queries as MongoDB is not supporting relations per se. What you can do though is take a look at aggregation pipeline and [`$lookup` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) specifically as that's a left join in disguise. ODM has a separate [aggregation builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/aggregation-builder.html#aggregation-builderhttp://) to help you with building stages, it's similar in use to the query builder.